# Unable to download data from my server fast in terminal

Tags: curl, ssh, download

I run unsuccessfully

```
curl $Masi@host:~/folder
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'host:~'
```

I have SSH-keys to the host.
I am trying to use curl similarly as scp.

**How can you use curl to download private data fast?**

Comment: just use scp: scp masi@host:~/folder .

Comment: Is there any special reason you want to use curl instead of scp?

Comment: @scraimer: There is no special reason. I just did not know first that you can use SCP the other way too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

curl is an HTTP client - you cannot use it as a SSH client.
What's wrong with SCP?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion that you can use SCP the other way too!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest reading the [man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) of cURL for some info about how to do this. I don't think that cURL can replace `scp` in the way you want it to.

If you have a secure FTP (SFTP) server or secure HTTP SSL (HTTPS) server, then cURL can accept SSH keys (although using an SSL key is more commonly accepted on the Internet.) It can use those keys to authenticate and establish a secure connection to the directories which have been **made public** to your user through the server.

To see how to pass SSH keys, see `--pubkey`, `--key`, and `--pass` in the [man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html).

It's important to understand that your home directory doesn't have to be available through such a server. Even if you authenticate with a user and a password. **`scp`** works through a different server, and will (by default) interpret paths as if you were logged in. So that relative paths are relative to your **home folder**, just like you expect.